# Performance of SIMD vectorized functions in Julia

Tags: julia, vectorization, simd

I am trying to test the first function on the github page of SIMD.jl (https://github.com/eschnett/SIMD.jl). This is the script:

```
using SIMD
using BenchmarkTools

function vadd!(xs::Vector{T}, ys::Vector{T}, ::Type{Vec{N,T}}) where {N, T}
  @assert length(ys) == length(xs)
  @assert length(xs) % N == 0
  lane = VecRange{N}(0)
  @inbounds for i in 1:N:length(xs)
      xs[lane + i] += ys[lane + i]
  end
end

b1 = Vector{Float64}([2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
b2 = Vector{Float64}([2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
c1 = Vec{8,Float64}((2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
c1t = typeof(c1)

@btime b1+b2
println(b1+b2)
@btime vadd!($b1, $b2, Vec{8, Float64})
println(b1)
@btime vadd!($b1, $b2, $c1t)
```

The results I get are not fully clear to me:

```
  57.739 ns (1 allocation: 144 bytes)
[4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 4.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0]
  18.400 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
[2.1001006e7, 2.1001006e7, 3.1501509e7, 4.2002012e7, 2.1001006e7, 2.1001006e7, 3.1501509e7, 4.2002012e7]
  127.009 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

The first call takes 57.739 ns, which is reasonable since the '+' operation should be already vectorised and it takes some extra time to allocate the memory required to allocate the output vector.

The second call seems successful in terms of computational time (18.400 ns). However, the output stored in b1 is totally wrong. Any idea?

The third is unclear as well to me. I am simply passing the type Vec using an auxiliary variables and the resulting function is almost one order of magnitude slower. The output result is wrong as well, but this is in line with the result of the second call. Any clue on this speed loss?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: With a mutating function like this, note that `btime` will run it many times while benchmarking, accumulating each iteration. You have to check b1 after calling it once normally to check the values. The performance difference eludes me though, i would suspect it might just be something happening with dispatch when running via benchmark tools macro, but i'm really not sure.

Comment: Just FYI, 18 nanoseconds (54 clock cycles on a 3GHz machine) is really slow for what should be two AVX `vaddpd` instructions (4 elements each).  Modern CPUs (Skylake / Zen2) can do the actual SIMD FP math work at 2x 256-bit vectors per clock cycle, although loading/storing the results will be limited to 4 elements per cycle (one 32-byte store of 4x float64).  I guess part of what's being timed is memory allocation / deallocation, and that's taking the majority of the time?  Either that or it's timing each iteration separately; huge timing overhead is normal for this tiny amount of work.